# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-location is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4]], but resolves to 16.0.0

Tags: android

I am getting this error while compiling my code. My project build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shubham.tommpas"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

}

dependencies {
//library required to display map
api 'com.tomtom.online:sdk-maps:2.+'
//library required for search
api 'com.tomtom.online:sdk-search:2.+'
//library required for routing
api 'com.tomtom.online:sdk-routing:2.+'
//library required for traffic
api 'com.tomtom.online:sdk-traffic:2.+'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.ankitdubey021:GPSTracker:2.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

What is the issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: i don't get it. what is the problem

Comment: did you fix this?

Answer (score -1):

add google() for repositories in gradle. if it is not there like below. If it is already there, it should be above than jcenter(). Please move it to up in both places. I also faced the same issue and this is how i fixed it.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
......
....


 allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

---

try it by excluding com.google.android.gms from "com.github.ankitdubey021:GPSTracker" dependency. Because it also use this dependency and it will transitively add to your gradle. Most probably it is the reason for your problem. you can exclude it like below by changing "com.github.ankitdubey021:GPSTracker".

```
implementation('com.github.ankitdubey021:GPSTracker') {
  exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}
```

Comment: now same error-The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-location is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: @MrRobot in your " com.github.ankitdubey021:GPSTracker" it use com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4 that's why u get an error like that. I thin it should be solve after u update your libraries like above. Please clean cache and rebuild again

Comment: @MrRobot I updated my answer again.  please revert that version changes and only exclude that "play-services" from "com.github.ankitdubey021:GPSTracker" like my answer. Please clean cache and all thing then build again